# Where is the best place to start a service?

Tags: android

I'd like to start a service when my app first boots up. i.e:

`startService(new Intent(this, ReminderService.class));`

One option is to do this in an activity, but I don't want to have to hit  specific place in the app for the service to start. Alternately was thinking of initializing in the Application object itself

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize Reminder Service
    startService(new Intent(this, ReminderService.class));
}
```

Is there a standard (idiomatic) place where I should be doing the initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the place where you decide to start it which is important, it is the mechanism which will stop it. Activity lifecycle is useful to handle this mechanism.